# Finding a conditional distribution for Test Statistic

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

NOTE: This is in further extension to my quest of understanding the paper discussion in question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657783/pdf-of-distances-in-the-circular-disk) (I will really appreciate any assistance, though I am myself trying to find the solution as well)

$$E = K\Omega\Phi\gamma \ \ \ (1)$$

Where $\Omega$ and $\Phi$ are two random variables with pdf as follows:

$$ f_\Omega(w) = \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}$$

[image]

Authors are interested in finding a Test Statistic $E$ and based on eq. (1), they claim that $E$ has the same distribution as  $\Omega$ for a given vaule of $\Phi$. The conditional PDF is hence found by authors as :

$$f_E(\varepsilon|\Phi) = \frac{K\Phi\gamma}{(K\Phi\gamma + \varepsilon)^2}$$

Where $\Omega = h_1^2/h_2^2$ and $h_1^2 \sim \exp(u)$ and $h_2^2 \sim \exp(u)$

My Questions are as following (in order)

(i)  How is eq. 2 obtained.

(ii) Why is $E$ has same distribution as $\Omega$

Comment: Just to clarify, are $K,\gamma$ constants?

Comment: Yes they are constants

Comment: No, it is the same as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The link is https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=Enhancing+Small+Cell+Transmission+Opportunity+Through+Passive+Receiver+Detection+in+Two-Tier+Heterogeneous+Networks&oq=Enhancing+Small+Cell+Transmission+Opportunity+Through+Passive+Receiver+Detection+in+Two-Tier+Heterogeneous+Networks&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.359j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Meanwhile, in the answer below, I have attached the snapshot of the paper as well

Comment: Sorry, I made a beginner's mistake in my comments. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\Phi$, we have the probability:
\begin{align}
P(E\leq \xi|\Phi) &= P(K\Phi\gamma\Omega \leq \xi|\Phi) \\
&= P\left(\left. \Omega\leq \frac{\xi}{K\Phi\gamma}\right|\Phi\right) \\
&= \frac{\frac{\xi}{K\Phi\gamma}}{1+\frac{\xi}{K\Phi\gamma}}\\
&=\frac{\xi}{K\Phi\gamma + \xi}
\end{align}
We differentiate this to obtain the PDF:
\begin{align}
f_E(\xi|\Phi)&=\frac{1}{K\Phi\gamma + \xi}-\frac{\xi}{(K\Phi\gamma + \xi)^2}\\
&=\frac{K\Phi\gamma}{(K\Phi\gamma + \xi)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks heaps...it was so simple. I am quite dumb not to realize that

Answer (score 0):

In the following is the snapshpt for the paper, I did not put it in the actual question to keep the question precise. Hence providing this image in here

[image]